# Empty employee list on careers ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Screenshot of Careers ad I was just shown, possible bug?

[image]

Comment: That's Alice, Bob and Chris; salt of the earth, you'll enjoy working with them. Not lookers, though, bless them.

Comment: There have been a few changes to how company page ads are rendered over the last few weeks, so I believe this is fixed now - I can't reproduce this and I haven't seen any other reports of this issue.